# Convolution neural network with limited amount of data

Tags: database, conv-neural-network

I built a convolution neural network for image classification that works successfully with large amount of data for each class, but I want to implements it with specific database with limited amount of data available for each class (e.g. may be 1, 2, 3). The accuracy of the same model will be very low in stead of I used data augmentation, batch normalization,and drop out. How can I raise the system accuracy with low amount of data available, is there some model specialized for this case, or any other addition to my system or editing to my image in order to get height evaluated accuracy system. Can anyone please help me, I'm confusing. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't do test with small amount of data you should try  it, conv net can work well even with limited amount of data, it's depend how "hard" classification task is.

few option I see with small amount of data:

- transfer learning (from you'r network trained with big data base, or for a more real world condition, from DCNN trained by google or other big one, since if you take weight from ur own CNN u'll never know if you could have achieve those performances with just small data base)
- If there is some research about ur classification task, find which feature ingeniering people do and apply it. Then try different classifier on extracted feature like SVM,randomforest... Look at ensemble learning and stacking model which are curetly used a lot

ps: for what I know there are 2 option to classify image. Automatic feature extraction which are done by neural network and "manual" feature extraction which can be identified by having a deep knowledge in the field, as a data scientist AND as a profesionnal of the field. 
When you have extractd you'r feature you can use different classifier, most of the people which extract feature with conv net use their neural network as classifier

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, yes I now trying to use transfer learning, I found some examples on google using weights of networks trained by google or other big ones, but I don't know how can I use weights of my pre-trained network on large database with my limited database. Can you please help me, I necessary need the classification of this limited database. Thanks a lot with regard..

Comment: If you take weight from you'r conv net trained on all the data and freeze all the layer, it'll be exactly the same thing than the cnn trained with all the data. If you unfreeze some layer (e.g last fully connected layer), it doesnt really make sens to do it because most of the model still has been trained on all the data.ps: I'm new in deep learning thing, I dont think i'm wrong but I could be... dont take it as the true verity

Comment: I hope this is understanble. Can you tel me why you try to create a CNN using just few data when you have a big data set ?

Comment: ok.. I didn't understand you'r question. I guess you'r 2 data set are different, but I guess you want to classify same kind of object. It's hard to classify image when you only have 1 training sample. You can look this kaggle challenge: they are trying to classify whale and more than 70% of target have only 1 image